# MSSQl Connection is busy with results for another hstmt

Tags: php, sql-server

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt, SQL state
>   S1000 in SQLExecDirect i

Comment: http://sourceitsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/06/connection-is-busy-with-results-for.html

Comment: Can you include the code or better highlight what you are trying to do?  This issue is usually caused by attempting to use an existing connection to retrieve another data reader while you have a reader open.